# grant a privilege for roles (for example editors) and higher

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, privileges

My wordpress theme has a custom post-type. Only editors (and higher) should be allowed to use this post type.

I did this with:

```
function add_capability($role,$cap) {
    $role_obj = get_role($role); // get the the role object
    $role_obj -> add_cap($cap); // add $cap capability to this role object
}

function set_cpt() {
    add_capability('editor', 'edit_cpt');
    add_capability('editor', 'read_cpt');
    add_capability('editor', 'delete_cpt');
    add_capability('editor', 'edit_cpt');
    add_capability('editor', 'edit_cpt');
    add_capability('editor', 'publish_cpt');
    add_capability('editor', 'read_cpt');
}
add_action('init', 'set_cpt');
```

<strike>(I think) in Wordpress 3.1 this was enough - all editors **and higher** had the right to use the post-type.</strike>

Now<strike>, in Wordpress 3.2</strike> **only** editors have the right to use the post-type.

Is there a way to grant privileges to role X and higher or would I have to mention every role?

Thank you!

[edit]

actually I found out that this never worked before. But is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin, you can set it up like you want. It also has the possibility to add custom roles (your `edit_cpt` and so on)

also a lot of plugins also work that way:

`<?php if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) { do_something(); } ?>`

Comment: thank you! The Members plugin would surely be a possibility. However I wanted to code it...

Comment: download the Members plugin, see how Justin coded it, copy what you need and paste it in your functions.php file?

Comment: In the Members plugin, you can choose the privileges for every role one by one. What I want to do is grant a privilege for ALL roles higher or equal to editor. Not that it would be a big deal to mention all roles one by one in the functions.php, I just want to know if there's a more general solution (for example using capability levels). (But I think levels are deprecated!?)

Comment: "grant a privilege for ALL roles higher or equal to editor", aren't that only the editor and the administrator Roles?
Perhaps you can look at a capability that both editor and administrator have, but the rest not.
A lot of plugins also work that way: <?php if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) { do_something(); } ?>

Comment: glad that eventually it works for you :)